# Can ssh-copy-id be configured to save to a different authorized_keys file?

Tags: ssh, openssh, key-authentication

Looking at the source of `ssh-copy-id` at [openssh-portable/ssh-copy-id at master · openssh/openssh-portable · GitHub](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/contrib/ssh-copy-id#L236) it looks like `ssh-copy-id` can copy the key to user specified `authorized_keys` files on the server, besides the default `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

However there doesn't seem to be a command line option for it, unless I'm looking at a different `ssh-copy-id`.

Comment: The part you link is a function that gets called with an additional parameter, depending upon the detected remote ssh server. eg dropbear gets a specific /etc/dropbear/authorized_keys destination which is different from default (openssh server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source file you mentioned, the commands may be executed as a remote shell skript, that is built on the fly on the local host. This is only used when `ssh-copy-id` does not use SFTP and the remote version is not *NetScreen*.

Then it could be possible if you change the environment variable `AUTH_KEY_FILE`.